# How to prove that $(A \bigtriangleup B) - C = (A - C) \bigtriangleup (B - C)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A,B,C$ be sets. Prove that $(A \bigtriangleup B) - C = (A - C) \bigtriangleup (B - C)$.

I've already checked the Venn diagrams and it seems like said identity is true but I have no idea how to prove it using known properties of sets and axioms from set theory. It'd be awesome if you could help me, thank you!

Comment: Please clarify exactly what the left-hand-side of your identity to be proved by using the parentheses.

Comment: I missed that, thank you! It's (A Δ B) - C = (A - C) Δ (B - C)

Comment: In general, you assume that an element x is in the left hand side of the equation and show that it must be in the right hand side, and then assume it is int he right hand side and show it must be in the left hand side as well.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to do exactly that but I'm afraid I might be doing it wrong. I'd like to see the "right" way of doing it, step by step.

Answer (score 2):

Go for two-way containment.

From left to right: if $x\in(A\triangle B) - C$ then $x$ is in exactly one of $A,B$ and not in $C$. Say, it's in $A$, then $x\in(A-C)$ but $x\notin B-C$, and thus $x\in(A-C)\triangle(B-C)$.

Can you do the other direction?

Answer (score 0):

$A-B=A\cap B' $

$(A\cup B)-C\ =\ (A\cup B)\cap C'\ =\ (A\cap C')\cup (B\cap C')$

(De morgan's law)

$=(A-C)\cup(B-C)$

Answer (score 0):

Since a point is either in a set or not, you only need to compare two truth tables with 3 variables or use some Boolean manipulation. This is entirely equivalent to using $\ ^c, \cup, \cap$, but I find it easier:

Fix some point $x$ and let $a$ be true **iff** $x \in A$ and similarly for $b,c$.

Then you want to show that $(a \bar{b} + \bar{a}b) \bar{c} $ is the same as 
$a \bar{c} \overline{b \bar{c}} + \overline{a \bar{c}}b \bar{c}$.

We have $(a \bar{b} + \bar{a}b) \bar{c} = a \bar{b}\bar{c} + \bar{a}b\bar{c}$ and
$a \bar{c} \overline{b \bar{c}} + \overline{a \bar{c}}b \bar{c} = a \bar{c} (\bar{b}+c) + (\bar{a}+c)b \bar{c} =a \bar{b}\bar{c} + \bar{a}b\bar{c}$.

Since this holds for all $x$ we have the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If $x \in (A \bigtriangleup B) - C$

Then we have that $x \in A\bigtriangleup B$ and that $x \not \in C$

If $x \in A\bigtriangleup B$ there are two cases.  Either

1) $x \in A$ but $x \not \in B$ or

2) $x \in B$ but $x \not \in A$.

If 1) Then $x \in A$ and $x \not \in C$ so $x \in A-C$.

But $x \not \in B$.  And if $x \not \in B$ it is not true that both $x \in B$ and $x \not \in C$ (although it is true $x \not \in C$, it *isn't* true that $x \in B$).

So $x \in A-C$ but $x \not \in B-C$ so $x \in (A-C)\bigtriangleup (B-C)$.

If 2) Then $x \in B$ and $x \not \in C$ so $x \in B-C$.

But $x \not \in A$.  And if $x \not \in A$ it is not true that both $x \in A$ and $x \not \in C$ (although it is true $x \not \in C$, it *isn't* true that $x \in A$).

So $x \in B-C$ but $x \not \in A-C$ so $x \in (A-C)\bigtriangleup (B-C)$

So either way $x \in (A-C)\bigtriangleup (B-C)$.

So we have $(A\bigtriangleup B) - C \subset (A-C)\bigtriangleup (B-C)$.

....

Now if $y \in (A-C)\bigtriangleup (B-C)$

we have two possible cases:

Either 1) $y \in A-C$ but $y\not \in B-C$ or

2) $y \in B-C$ but $y \not \in A-C$.

If 1) Then $y \in A-C$ so $y\in A$ and $y \not \in C$.  But $y \not \in B-C$ which means if $y \in B$ than $y$ can't not be $C$ so $y \in C$.  By $y$ isn't in $C$ so $y$ can't be in $B$ at all.

So we have $y \in A$ and $y \not \in B$.  So $y \in A\bigtriangleup B$.  And $y \not \in C$ so $y \in (A\bigtriangleup B)-C$.

If 2) then $y \in B-C$ so $y\in B$ but $y\not \in C$.  But $y \not \in A-C$ so there is no way $y\in A$ unless $y \in C$. but $y\not\in C$ so $y\not \in A$.

So we have $y \in B$ and $y\not \in A$ so $y \in A\bigtriangleup B$.  And $y\not \in C$ so $y \in (A\bigtriangleup B)-C$.

So either way 
$y \in (A\bigtriangleup B)-C$

So $(A-C)\bigtriangleup (B-C)\subset (A\bigtriangleup B)-C$.

So $(A-C)\bigtriangleup (B-C)$ and $(A\bigtriangleup B)-C$ are subsets of each other and they are therefore equal to each other.